# INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY, is there any islamic evidence for or against it?

Tags: sunnah, property

the most widely used definition for **intellectual property** is,

*Intellectual property (IP) refers to creations of the mind, such as inventions; literary and artistic works; designs; and symbols, names and images used in commerce.*

i understand that anything created for the betterment of the muslim ummah and to please Allah (S.W) is allowed and not haram, generally speaking.

my question is, **is there any evidence from the quran and authentic sunnah to support *specifically* intellectual property?**.

though this concept is coined much later, i would like to know if there are evidences from the time of the prophet PBUH. in my layman's effort, i have come across some but i would refrain from mentioning them here because i doubt the authenticity of those and also to provide a more wider and fresh angle, for the persons providing answers.

Comment: One of the evidences for it is ([5:1](https://legacy.quran.com/5/1)). One against it is the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4169): “A wise word is the lost property of the believer, so wherever he finds it, he has more right to it.”

Comment: @Medi1Saif the verse you mentioned (5:1), i could not find any direct relation to my query as the verse refers to obligations and treaties. in one sense it is applicable but need more corroborating evidence to support that. and that hadith you mentioned is graded weak. can you elaborate a little more if it's possible, as i am interested to know how you connect verse 5:1, i am not well versed in this field.

Comment: This verse refers to any kind of contracts.